# cannot call a method on a null-valued expression - how to solve it

Tags: windows, powershell, unzip

I have written a script that gets the zip file from a specific folder and unzip the file to a specific folder.

please check the below codes

```
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace("C:\Users\jhnayak\Views_Seagate\jhnayak_DDTools_Phase14_Dev\apps\ddcli\build\win\\..\\..\\..\\..\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel\mptlib2_rel.zip")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace("C:\Users\jhnayak\Views_Seagate\jhnayak_DDTools_Phase14_Dev\apps\ddcli\build\win\\..\\..\\..\\..\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel")
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())

$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel" + "\$filename")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel")
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
```

for both the codes i got the same error, please check below

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:38
+ $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items <<<< ())
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (items:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

when i hardcoded the path without using \..\ in between it worked perfectly.

please check the below code

```
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace("C:\Users\jhnayak\Views_Seagate\jhnayak_DDTools_Phase14_Dev\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel\mptlib2_rel.zip")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace("C:\Users\jhnayak\Views_Seagate\jhnayak_DDTools_Phase14_Dev\sas2_rel\mptlib2_rel")
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
```

but i would like to use the earlier one, so that the path should not be hard coded, it should work for all paths.

What is causing this error?
What exactly is my null valued expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try parsing the path before passing it to `$shell_app.namespace()`. There is a handy method in .Net that does just that: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()`. Like so,

```
$relativeLoc = "...build\win\\..\\..\\..\\..\sas2..." # Complex dynamic path
$parsedLoc = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath($relativeLoc) # Get absolute path
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($parsedLoc)
```

As a bonus, you can use `Test-Path` to check that the target `$parsedLoc` exists.

Answer (score 0):

This post is ancient, but for anyone else running into similar problems and going absolutely insane:

When passing variables to `Shell.Application.Namespace`, the variable needs to be wrapped in quotes to work properly.

Example:

```
$zipPath = <some_filepath_here>
$destinationPath = <some_directorypath_here>

$shellApp=New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$zipFile = $shellApp.Namespace("$zipPath") # PUT THE QUOTES HERE
$destination = $shellApp.Namespace("$destinationPath") # ALSO PUT THE QUOTES HERE

$destination.CopyHere($zipFile.Items())
```

Note: you seemingly also have to use absolute paths for these variables, throw in a `$zipPath = Resolve-Path $zipPath` or just use absolute paths in the first place. The destination also has to exist, make sure to create it if it doesn't.